# is DynamoDB throughput based on same partition or many diff partition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I could not find it on AWS doc (or I just miss that).

Is the throughput (write/sec) defined in AWS
based on items stored on a single partition? (so if I do my partition better can give me more write)

or just based on an ideal partition (so if my partition is bad, say only have 1 partition, I can never reach the write/sec for my table?  )

Thanks for reading.
Help me please~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughput (write/sec) defined in AWS is for all partitions.

if your throughput is 1000 (write) and you have 10 partitions and if all items distributed the same between partitions, then you will get 100/10 = 10 write capacity for each partition

if items have bad distribution (one partition has 'hot' keys, or more keys then another), the this partition can get more capacity, but its mean that other partitions will get less capacity.

if you have only partition, then all your write throughput is on this partitions (no matter how keys distributed inside this partition)

Comment: So its quite stable no matter how good or how bad my partition is? What if my partition quality change over time?

Comment: you really need to worry about is  how you wont get another partition. if your partition will be split to 2 partitions, then your partition quality is important. your partition can split if (1) have more then 10GB on partitions, (2) if you increased your throughput (not documented how much throughput a partition can has, but its around 1000(read+write) ) (3) if you have many read/write on same partitions (that can be handled)